# Why doesn't Mike Ross have a profile in Sheila's documents when he already went to Harvard?

Tags: suits

In season 3 or 4, Louis Litt digs through Sheila's documents trying to find the profile of Mike Ross, but he is unable to -- indicating that Mike Ross never went to Harvard.

But, in another flashback, they tell us that Mike Ross went to Harvard school and got expelled because he sold an exam to the dean's daughter:

> In a third season flashback episode, **it is revealed that Mike was accepted into Harvard Law ten years before the series began**; however, Trevor was caught selling a calculus test that Mike had memorized, which put him in danger of expulsion. In order to save Trevor, Mike confessed, **believing the dean wouldn't go to such extremes in punishing him**. But it is revealed the test was sold to the dean's daughter, resulting in the university board demanding the dean's resignation. As his last act, the dean expels Mike then further punishes him by calling Harvard to inform them of his transgressions.

If he already went to Harvard and got expelled, then he already should have a profile in Sheila's document, but he didn't, why? Is that a flaw in the series?

Comment: It's been a while, but if I remember correctly, she's in care of the "post-graduated". She "notes" Law Firms, and dispatch accordingly the graduated student looking for jobs/internship in function of the "note" of the firm and the ranking of the student. So, since Mike didn't graduate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He never went to Harvard. He was expelled from another university after he had been accepted to Harvard as a transfer student. This expulsion prevented his transferring.

See [Mike Ross page on Suits Wikia](http://suits.wikia.com/wiki/Mike_Ross) (spoilers).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just realized that.

Answer (score 1):

Sheila Sazs only keeps records about graduates. [As Wikipedia explains (beware: SPOILERS for later seasons if you click that link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Suits_characters):

> Sheila Sazs (Rachael Harris) is a high-level official in the Harvard
>   Law School placement department, **whose job is to place graduates as
>   associate attorney positions at law firms**. As such, she works with
>   recruiters from top law firms such as Pearson Hardman, always trying
>   to get maximum return for her graduates.